# Integral of Binomial Distribution curve

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, binomial-distribution

I attempted to solve for the definite integral for a binomial distribution:

[image]

I tried to solve through integration by parts but could not. In addition, I am not sure how to go past the factorial. How would I find this integral? Any help is appreciated, I am still relatively new to integration.

Comment: $x$ is an integer so simple integration over $x$ may not be the right approach

Comment: The binomial distribution is a *discrete* one. Where the integral comes from?..

Comment: @metamorphy not quite sure what you mean...the integral can be calculated on software like Desmos/Wolfram Alpha. I just want to know how I could manually solve this (if possible). This is a sort of substitute for finding the cdf...

Comment: $x!$ and $(n-x)!$ are not defined for non-integer $x$ and non-integer $n-x$ unless you extend them with the gamma function. Integration is defined over real numbers not integers, so $\int f(x)dx$ is not meaningful if $x$ is an integer (unless you define such integration as summation). Wolfram alpha can compute it because it (explicitly) assumes its over a real interval, not a set of integers. In fact wolfram is likely computing $\int_0^a \frac{n!}{\Gamma(x+1) \Gamma(n-x+1)} p^x (1-p)^{(n-x)} dx$, which is rigorously defined.

Comment: @BLRBoy anyway if you want to find the CDF this is the incorrect route. By definition, for discrete RVs, the CDF is defined by $F_X(k)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq k)=\sum_{j\leq k} \mathbb{P}(X=j)$ and so in the case of a binomial RV the CDF is given by the sum $\sum_{j=0}^k {n \choose j} p^j(1-p)^{n-j}$ which has no simple closed form as far as I know, at least not without special functions.

Comment: @BLRBoy In which **context** does this term appear?

Comment: @NapD.Lover thanks for the comment. I understand better now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$. Then the distribution function of $X$ is $$F_X(x) := \mathbb P(X\leqslant x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} \mathbb P(X=k). $$
This sum does not have a nice closed form; the best we can do is
$$
\mathbb P(X\leqslant a) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor a\rfloor} \binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = (n-a)\binom na\int_0^{1-p} t^{n-a-1}(1-t)^a\ \mathsf dt.
$$
If $a\leqslant np$ then we can derive some upper bounds for the lower tail of the distribution function. Hoeffding's inequality yields
$$
F_X(a)\leqslant \exp\left(-2\frac{(np-a)^2}n\right),
$$
and Chernoff's inequality yields
$$
F_X(a) \leqslant \exp\left(-\frac1{2p}\cdot\frac{(np-a)^2}n \right).
$$